Understanding the definiton of independent random variables
I am learning about propability theory, and I am trying to understand the definition of independent random variables. I will write down the definition of independence I learned until now in probability. (Please note that I am not really familiar with measure theory. I do know the definitions of probability measure and  $\sigma-algebra$.)
Independence of two events:

Definition:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Two events $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$ are called independent if $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$.

After that the definition was "generalized" to a family of events:
Independence of family of events:

Definition
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.A family of events $A_1,A_2,...$ is called independent if for all
$i_1<i_2<...<i_k$: $\mathbb{P}(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap ... \cap A_{i_k})=\mathbb{P}(A_{i_1})\mathbb{P}(A_{i_2})...\mathbb{P}(A_{i_k})$.

Independent random variables:
This section started with the remark that we view random variables as maps from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ to $(Im(X),2^{Im(X)},\mathbb{P}_X)$,where
$Im(X)$ denotes the image of $X$, $2^{Im(X)}$ the powerset if $Im(X)$ and $\mathbb{P}_X$ the probability measure induced by $X$.
This induces a \sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ by defining $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(2^{Im(X)})$.
The following definition does not depend on $X$ having a discrete image.

Definition(Independent families):
Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and $(\mathcal{F}_i) \subset \mathcal{F}$. The family $(\mathcal{F_i}_{i \in I})$ is called independent, if for every finite subset $J \subset I$ and every selection $E_j \in \mathcal{F_j}, j \in J$:
$\mathbb{P}(\cap_{j \in J}E_j)=\prod_{j \in J} \mathbb{P}(E_j)$.

With this definition we defined the independence of random variables as:

Definition (Independent random variables):
A family $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ of random variables is called independend if the family $(\sigma(X_i))_{i \in I}$ of $\sigma$-algabras is independent as in the above definition.

What I do understand and what not:
I do understand the first two definitions, as they are just the "normal" definition of independence of events. I do not understand the definitons $3$ and $4$. Regarding $3$, I am confused on why we suddenly have families of $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal{F_i}$. Ragarding $4$, I do not what $\sigma(X_i)$ should be. It was mentioned that in the discrete case, we can define $\sigma(X)$ as $X^{-1}(2^{Im(X)})$ but I do not know what $\sigma(X)$ should be in the non-discrete case.
(I do not know if the non-discrete case is just mentioned for the sake of completeness.)

For 3 - we switch to families of sets, because it will be needed for 4. Informally, "independence" of several "things" means that "information" about some of them doesn't "give information" about the rest. For events the "information" is simply if event occured or not. For random variables it's in general more complicated, as we can ask "if random variable is in $[-1, 2] \cup [42, 99]$" - and random variables are independent if no question about one of them "helps" to answer any question about the other.
For 4 - your confusion makes sense, because such definition of random variable is not enough. You need to also have $\sigma$-algebra on co-domain. And saying that random variable maps to induced probability measure makes no sense.
Correct definition of random variable. Given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and some other measurable space (support and $\sigma$-algebra) $(\Psi, \mathcal G)$, function $X: \Omega \to \Psi$ is random variable if for every $\mathcal G$-measurable $T \subseteq \Psi$, it's preimage $X^{-1}(T)$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable.
Then $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$, $\sigma(X)$, is just collection of preimages of all measurable sets (exercise: prove it's indeed $\sigma$-algebra).
Now let $\Omega = \Psi = \{0, 1\}$, $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$, $\mathcal P(T) = \frac{|T|}{2}$, $X(\omega) = \omega$, $Y(\omega) = 1 - \omega$.
Then if $\mathcal G = \mathcal F$, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. If $\mathcal G = \{\varnothing, \Psi\}$, they are independent.
So, independence of random variables can depend on algebra on target space ("questions we can ask"), and we can't omit it from definition.
